# Hard system, Three equations, three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Let $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2},z_{1},z_{2},\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Solve the system for $a,b,c$

$$\frac{ay_{1}-bx_{1}}{\sqrt{\left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2}}}+\frac{ay_{2}-bx_{2}}{\sqrt{\left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}}}=0$$

$$\frac{c-z_{1}}{\sqrt{\left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2}}}+\frac{c-z_{2}}{\sqrt{\left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}}}=0$$

$$a^{2}+b^{2}=\theta ^{2}$$

My attempt to solve the problem, in fact it is only algebra, but I still have a chaos when trying to eliminate the variables

Manipulating the first two equations:

$\left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2} \right)$

$\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2} \right)$

$\left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2} \right)$

$\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{1} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2} \right)$

$\left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2}\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)$

$\left( \left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}-\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)^{2}\left( c-z_{1} \right)^{2} \right)\left( \left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2} \right)=0$

then
$\left( a-x_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( b-y_{2} \right)^{2}+\left( c-z_{2} \right)^{2}=0$

or

$\left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)\left( c-z_{2} \right)+\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)\left( c-z_{1} \right)=0$

or

$\left( ay_{1}-bx_{1} \right)\left( c-z_{2} \right)-\left( ay_{2}-bx_{2} \right)\left( c-z_{1} \right)=0$

Comment: What are you trying to do? I am almost sure that there is a shortcut